# Webfonts with Brunch

Tags: build, webfonts, brunch

Converting from **Grunt** to **Brunch**, and I would like to convert my `.svg` icons in the folder `fonts/` to cross-browser compatible webfonts (`woff`, `eot`, `ttf`, etc) but I haven't found such plugins for **Brunch**.

Something similar like: [github.com/sapegin/grunt-webfont](https://github.com/sapegin/grunt-webfont)

I've been looking at some different approaches, like building my own brunch-plugin and wrapping with an existing library ([Font Custom](http://fontcustom.com/)).

Any suggestions on a better approach? Or are there any webfonts-plugins I've missed for Brunch?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this having a similar issue and solved it with a Brunch-referenced plugin: copyfilemon

https://github.com/kasselTrankos/copyfilemon-brunch

```
$ npm install copyfilemon-brunch
```

Add this to your Brunch config under "plugins" (I use coffee-script and bower for managing bootstrap):

```
copyfilemon:
  'fonts': 'bower_components/bootstrap/fonts'
```

This will copy all files from 'bower_components/bootstrap/fonts' into our Brunch configured public directory under the sub-folder 'fonts'.

Note: It will copy the files every time you run/watch Brunch, which should not do any harm other than taking up some resources for a few ms.